# Как лучше задать вес значениям в словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Есть большой словарь, в котором записи являются словарями такого вида:

```
"Smth": {
    "name": "Text",
    "enemies": [
        "enemy1",
        "enemy2",
        "enemy3"
    ],
    "friends": [
        "friend1",
        "friend2",
        "friend3"
    ]
},
```

Нужно придать вес всем значениям из `enemies` и `friends`, которые всегда будут извлекаться вместе с этим весом. Например, `enemy1` имеет вес `0.4`, а `friend3` имеет вес `0.8`. Для каждого значения вес будет указываться вручную.

Как это лучше сделать? Пока что сделал только такой способ:

```
    "enemies": [
        ["enemy1", 0.4],
        ["enemy2", 0.3],
        ["enemy3", 0.7]
    ]
```

Подходит ли он или есть вариант лучше? Скорость в приоритете. Спасибо.

UPD: Нужен именно такой формат, потому что эти словари будут записаны в `.json` файл.

Comment: Кортежем, возможно, будет быстрее: `"enemies": [("enemy1", 0.4), ("enemy2", 0.3)]`

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Да, насчет кортежа, это вроде бы не вариант, так как эти словари потом будут храниться в `json` файле. Если не ошибаюсь, там нет кортежей, только лишь списки. Забыл упомянуть.

Comment: Если бы скорость не была в приоритете, я бы сделал `enemy1` словарем, с полем `weight`, что дало бы возможность добавлять врагам и другие свойства в последствии.

Comment: ничто не мешает вам красивый класс, который читаемый код порождает, и сериализацию объектов этого класса в json одновременно иметь. К примеру, `WeigthedItem = namedtuple('WeightedItem', 'id weight')`, а при сохранении как json: `default=lambda o: list(o) if isinstance(o, WeightedItem) else json.Encoder().default(o)`. А так *"Лучше"* это субъективно: если код делает что хочется, простой, читаемый и работает со скоростью достаточной в вашем случае, то улучшения в другим местах лучше пытаться делать. Явно укажите конкретную проблему с кодом (читаемость, потребляемая память, скорость).

Answer (score 1):

collections — High-performance container datatypes:
[namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

```
enemy = namedtuple('Item', ['name', 'weight'])
enemies = [
    enemy('enemy1', weight=.4),
    enemy('enemy2', .3),
    enemy('enemy3', .7)
]
e = enemies[2]

print(e)
print(e.weight)
name, weight = e
print(name, e[1])
```

out:

```
Item(name='enemy3', weight=0.7)
0.7
enemy3 0.7
```